# Probability of a specific order of outcomes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there is a student who wanders into a classroom to take an exam that he is not prepared for. There are four multiple choice questions on the exam, each with four given answers to select from. There is only one correct solution for each question. What is the probability that the student gets the first and third questions correct, but misses the second and fourth questions?

This problem is nested in a binomial distribution question, but the binomial distribution doesn't seem to apply here since it only tells you the probability of a certain number of successes.

My initial thought is to just multiply the respective probability for each question, i.e., $\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}$, but that would only tell you the probability that the student gets *any* two questions correctly. My second thought is to divide that quantity by 7 since there are seven possible ways for the student to get two questions correctly (assuming that order doesn't matter).

Any thoughts or insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ... also, there are $6$ ways to arrange two successes and two failures.  $6 ~= ~4!/2!^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My initial thought is to just multiply the respective probability for each question, i.e., $\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{3}{4}$, but ...

No buts.   That is the answer.   That is the probability for obtaining: first is correct, second is incorrect, third is correct, and fourth is incorrect.   Ie: two correct and two incorect results in the specified order.

Comment: Order matters for this event *because* it was specified.

Comment: Answer is correct because the conditional probabilities cancel out.